# How do I set logo and launchers in Jupyterlab and Jupyterhub?

Tags: jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I'm trying to customize Jupyterhub and Jupyterlab my goal is to remove/change Logos and Launchers.

Questions are:

- For Jupyterhub I'm trying to remove the logo setting c.Jupyterhub.logo_file to none, that's an option on jupyterhub_config.py near spawner_class. Is it possible?
- How do I remove Jupyterlab Launcher? I already tryed to remove this feature using jupyter labextension disable @jupyterlab/launcher-extension while building the image but it didn't worked.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the launcher? This would prevent users from creating new notebooks and files from the main area. Is this what you intend to do?

Comment: No, I didn't explained this part correctly, in reality I want to remove the launcher gif. Everytime I press f5 while in jupytelab a gif indicating that it is loading apears until jupyterlab is all loaded, the gif is similar to this picture. I want to remove it or change it to another gif. https://miro.medium.com/max/1036/1*FogMIj4gYwp3fTHLZuwavQ.png

Comment: I get what you mean. This is not what `@jupytrelab/launcher-extension` does (it provides the default screen allowing to *launch* new notebooks or create files). Could you please update your question? To clarify what you want to achieve (just to make it easier for others to read)?

Answer (score 3):

For the logo, I am not sure about JupyterHub-specific solutions, but you could see how [Elyra](https://github.com/elyra-ai/elyra) does that for their JupyterLab distribution with Elyra theme extension [here](https://github.com/elyra-ai/elyra/blob/4b8fab592b111ead8e41b7dff3b0497b0e9a7d9e/packages/theme/src/index.ts#L61-L78) (under Apache License, so it should not be pasted in here). In short they first locate the icon in the "top" area of `JupyterFrontEnd.shell` (which implements `IShell` interface) using [`IShell.widgets`](https://jupyterlab.github.io/jupyterlab/interfaces/_application_src_index_.jupyterfrontend.ishell.html#widgets) and then write their own icon into the located container.

A better approach is to disable `@jupyterlab/application-extension:logo` plugin using `disabledExtensions` and provide your own!

For the replacing the initial animation, you would want to swap the [`@jupyterlab/apputils-extension:splash`](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/997f3af68396539136ab0cb8512c73c07e021e4a/packages/apputils-extension/src/index.ts#L156-L163) plugin, not the launcher extension. Launcher is what allows users to start new notebooks from the main area widget.